# Python: Creating Term Document Matrix from list

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

So I wanted to train a Naive Bayes Algorithm over some documents and the below code would just run fine if I had documents in the form of strings. But the issues is the strings I have goes through a series of pre-processing step which is more then stopword remove, lemmatization etc rather there are some custom conversion which returns a list of ngrams, where n can [1,2,3] depending on the context of text. 
So now since I have list of ngram instead of a string representing a document I am confused how can I represent the same as an input to CountVectorizer.
Any suggestions?

Code that would work fine with docs as a document array of type string.

```
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary='true')
data = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)

tfidf_data = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit_transform(data)
classifier = BernoulliNB().fit(tfidf_data,op)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should combine all your pre-processing steps into preprocessor and maybe tokenizer functions, see [section 4.2.3.10](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#customizing-the-vectorizer-classes) and [CountVectorizer description](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn-feature-extraction-text-countvectorizer) from scikit-learn docs. For example of such tokenizers/transformers see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126442/combining-text-stemming-and-removal-of-punctuation-in-nltk-and-scikit-learn) of [src code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L176) of scikit-learn itself.